# How can I type a default export using Flow?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, flowtype

## How can I type a default export using Flow? Does Flow have a way of accomplishing this?

### Desired Outcome:

```
// index.js
type complexThing = {
  a: string
}
type Thing = {
  x: number,
  y: boolean,
  z: complexThing
}

export default {
 x: 0,
 y: true,
 z: {a: 'hello'}
} : Thing // this says my default export is a Thing
```

### Acceptable Alternative:

Alternatively, I wouldn't mind typing each of the object properties inline, but I think that's syntactically impossible:

```
export default {
 // I don't know how to add type signatures here
 x: 0, // number
 y: true, // boolean
 z: {a: 'hello'} // complexThing
}
```

### Not What I Want:

What I *don't* want to do is store a variable just to to Flow type it:

```
// index.js
type complexThing = {
  a: string
}
type Thing = {
  x: number,
  y: boolean,
  z: complexThing
}

const myThing: Thing = {
 x: 0,
 y: true,
 z: {a: 'hello'}
}

export default myThing
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are doing a [typecast](https://flowtype.org/docs/syntax.html#typecasts) so you will need parens around the object, e.g. change

```
export default {
  x: 0,
  y: true,
  z: {a: 'hello'}
} : Thing
```

to

```
export default ({
  x: 0,
  y: true,
  z: {a: 'hello'}
} : Thing)
```

Comment: Aha, yes I see now. `export default {}` is an expression, so it requires a typecast to capture the type signature. The same thing would work for typing the object properties inline via object literal:
`export default {
x: (0: number)
}`

Thanks!