# Flow Coverage: export default ReactComponent warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

In a file like this:

```
// index.js
// @flow
import Layout from './Layout';
import LayoutActions from './LayoutActions';

export { LayoutActions };
export default Layout; // flow-coverage-report complains that Layout is of type any
```

How can I add a type to the default export?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41992496/how-can-i-type-a-default-export-using-flow, doesn't it?

Comment: True, it's very similar. It works. But I still have problems with typing in this file. After adding the type, flow-coverage-report stills reports that the line isn't covered by flow. The line looks like: `export default (Layout: React.Node)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I type a default export using Flow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41992496/how-can-i-type-a-default-export-using-flow)